# React Router Prompt Overriding

Tags: reactjs, prompt, react-router-v4

I'm using `React Router Prompt` to block the navigation to another route if the form is half filled.

Everything is working fine, but `Prompt` is throwing default browser confirm box.

According to the requirement I need to render Custom Dilog Box.

Could any one suggest me how to override browser default confirm box with custom dilog box.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good guide for anyone who comes across this question . https://medium.com/@michaelchan_13570/using-react-router-v4-prompt-with-custom-modal-component-ca839f5faf39

Note: if you are not blocking navigation to specific urls but rather prompting based whenever someone leaves a page that has the RouteLeavingGuard. Call useHistory/useLocation inside the RouteLeavingGuard that way the only think you need is the when prop

ex:

```
 const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState<Location | null>(null);

  const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = useState(false);

  const history = useHistory();

  const { pathname } = useLocation();



  const closeModal = (): void => {

    setModalVisible(false);

  };

  const handleBlockedNavigation = (nextLocation: Location): boolean => {

    if (!confirmedNavigation && pathname) {

      setModalVisible(true);

      setLastLocation(nextLocation);

      return false;

    }

    return true;

  };

  const handleConfirmNavigationClick = (): void => {

    setModalVisible(false);

    setConfirmedNavigation(true);

  };

  useEffect(() => {

    if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation) {

      // Navigate to the previous blocked location with your navigate function

      history.push(lastLocation.pathname);

    }

  }, [confirmedNavigation, history, lastLocation]);
```